# Error when reinstalling Android SDK

Tags: android, development-environment

I am creating a USB with all the tools I need for a Linux-based development environment, including the Android SDK. When I run `./android`, I get the following error

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: invalid character at position 2 in 08
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: NumberFormat invalid character at position 2 in 08
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
```

What does "invalid character at position 2" mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have an unsupported JVM, probably Gij. Install the OpenJDK JRE or the <s>Sun</s> Oracle JRE, and make sure that `java` on your path is that one.

Thanks to [ch…](http://code.google.com/u/114249146237177022085/) in [Issue 37989: tools/android update sdk --no-ui won't work](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37989) (and I confirm).

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that worked for me on linux.

1) Check your java version: java -version, for me appears this one
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.6.3

As I has installed the version jdk1.6.0_24 I wanted to have that version when I do java -version so I've looked in PATH variable (echo $PATH) and I've realized that the inclusion of my jdk1.6.0_24 was at the end of the path. So I included the path to my jdk1.6.0_24 to be at the beginning to the PATH variable.

Now when I run: java -version, appears:
java version "1.6.0_24"

2) Now go to your Android sdk folder (.../sdk/tools/) and run ./android

In my case the Android SDK Manager opened without problem.

I hope it helps!

When

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I hope others will find it helpful in the future.